# Making Wordpress Site 100% Browser Width

Tags: html, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I'm building a wordpress site using a theme from templatemonster called Shared Space you can find here (https://www.templatemonster.com/wordpress-themes/64066.html). My question is in the backend of admin panel the let you set the width of the site in pixels. But will not let you use percentages. I dabbled around and found in chrome inspect if I disable max-width 1200px and put the max-width to 100% the site because full screen. My only issue is inspect only shows (index):373 and I can't find this line in the style.css file.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)(index):373
.site .container {
    /* max-width: 1200px; */
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The above code is found under this class of inspector:

```
 <div class="top-panel__container container">
```

Here is the website I am working on: http://www.rodgersgroupllc.com/newsite/

I did try to copy this to the additional css area of customizing wordpress but it doesn't seem to over ride this. Could someone please tell me what I can do to get this site true full screen left to right?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your css file override your class. Did your try the !important ?
`.site .container { max-width: 100% !important; }` or `body .site .container { max-width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom CSS to wordpress site, you can find custom CSS option under appearance > theme > custom css. Here you can write your custom CSS and override your theme's default CSS.

Comment: I already tried that. I put @media (min-width: 1200px)(index):373
.site .container {
    /* max-width: 1200px; */
    max-width: 100%;
} But it didn't work. The site still loaded at 1200px wide. I can set in the backend a Width but only in Pixels not percentage. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @FrankG. You can try CSS specificity like mentioned --

.top-panel.invert top.panel__container.container {
  max-wdth: 100%;
}